# Как удалить определённую строку из .txt файла

Tags: python, файлы

Я хочу найти в файле `users.txt` определённую строку (например, СОДЕРЖАЩУЮ `"Привет"`), и удалить эту строку. Я облазил всё - ничего не нашел с моим случаем. И да - покажите легко, не нужно делать огромные непонятные коды. **Задача проста - найти и удалить определённую строку из .txt файла**

Comment: Оффтоп: Даже если задача звучит просто, это не значит, что она проста в реализации.

Comment: А что может быть сложного в ПРОСТОМ УДАЛЕНИИ строки? Я понимаю, сам не умею т.к. начинающий. Но логично же - просто удалить строку.

Comment: Ну формально - прочитать файл в массив (один элемент - одна строка), найти элемент с заданной (под)строкой, удалить его из массива, записать массив в файл. И по дороге не потерять порядок строк (элементов в массиве).

Comment: Разве нет такой команды, вроде for line in f: if "lol" in line: line.clear() ???

Comment: И что по вашему код должен сделать после line.clear()? Допустим, он очистит место на диске, которое занимает эта строчка. Но файл по прежнему будет иметь ту же длину, только теперь с последовательностью нулевых байт в середине, там, где была строка! По любому нужно как минимум сместить все строки, которые идут после удалённой.

Comment: Нет такого понятия - удаление из файла (как устройства последовательного доступа). Либо считать всё в список, удалить ненужное, записать список в тот же файл, либо читать построчно, как вы уже умеете, записывая в выходной файл только хорошие строки, потом удалить старый файл, переименовать новый.

Comment: @Vayton, если вы в текстовом редакторе удалите одну строчку из текстового файла в котором 1.000.000 строк, то текстовый редактор пересоздаст файл и запишет в него 999.999 строк.

Comment: @Александр, мне не нужно смещать строки! Главное - удалить строку! Я то их могу потом сам смещать или скрипт для этого создать!

Comment: Если не смещать последующие строки, то что вы вообще вкладываете в понятие "удалить строку"? Допустим у вас есть строка из 20 букв, которую нужно удалить. И после удаления у вас между предыдущей и следующей строкой останется 20 пробелов? Или 20 нулевых байтов?

Comment: Я могу удалить эти строчки сам, когда их накопится немного.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Открываем файл для чтения.
Сохраняем все строки в массив `lines`

Открываем файл для записи.
Проходим по массиву строк и сравниваем с искомой строкой.
Если строка не найдена - записываем строку в файл.

UPD. С учетом предложений @MaxU

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

with open('f.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

str = 'Hello'
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str))
with open('f.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in lines:
        result = pattern.search(line)
        if result is None:
            f.write(line)
```

Или почти тоже самое, но в один проход (но я за первый вариант)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

str = 'Hello'
pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str))
with open('f.txt', 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)
    for line in lines:
        result = pattern.search(line)
        if result is None:
            f.write(line)
        f.truncate()
```

Источники:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710067/using-python-for-deleting-a-specific-line-in-a-file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128144/replace-string-within-file-contents

Comment: 1. лучше вынести `pattern = re.compile(r'Hello')` за тело цикла. 2. `pattern.match()` - найдёт только строки, которые __начинаются__ со слова `Hello`, а не те, которые содержат `Hello`

Comment: `re.compile(r'^.*' + re.escape(str) + r'.*$')` --> `pattern = re.compile(re.escape(str)); result = pattern.search(line)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Читайте из одного файла, записывайте в другой файл:

```
FIND = "Привет"
INFILE = "users.txt"
OUTFILE = "output.txt"
ENC = "utf-8"

with open(INFILE, encoding=ENC) as infile, open(OUTFILE, "w", encoding=ENC) as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if FIND not in line:
            outfile.write(line)
```

После этого вы можете переименовать выводной файл:

```
import os

os.remove(INFILE)
os.rename(OUTFILE, INFILE)
```

---

*Пример вводного файла* `users.txt`:

```
Здравствуйте, друзья!
Всем привет!
Как дела?
Привет всем!
Всем девушкам.
```

*В результате будет файл* `users.txt` *таким:*

> ```
> Здравствуйте, друзья!
> Всем привет!
> Как дела?
> Всем девушкам.
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Вместо `if FIND not in line:` возможно использовать `if FIND.lower() not in line.lower():`, чтобы не делать разницу между строчными и прописными буквами. Тогда результат будет

> ```
> Здравствуйте, друзья!
> Как дела?
> Всем девушкам.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожим вопросом: есть файл с исходным текстом, нужно удалить из него строки, в начале которых нет определенных слов, а затем результат поместить в новый файл.

Поскольку `del` для строк применять нельзя, пошел другим путем: заменил содержимое строки на пробел (чем не очищение?), а затем убрал пробел методом `strip`:

```
path = 'C:/Users/ПК/Desktop/kes_2018.txt'
d = open(path)
d = d.readlines()
for x in d:
    if x.startswith('Определение'):
        npos = x.find('N')
        x = x[npos+2:]
    elif x.startswith('Требование'):
        x = x[x.find(' ') + 1 :]+'\n'
    else:
        x = x.replace(x, ' ')
        x = x.strip()
with open('C:/Users/ПК/Desktop/result.txt','a') as k:
    k.write(x)
```