# Как удалить ссылку из txt

Tags: python

Подскажите как можно удалить ссылку из .txt после использования. Is_img.txt - тут хранятся ссылки на картинки.

'''

```
 with open ('ls_img.txt') as file
                             
      lines = file.readlines()
                       
      random_line = random.choice(lines)
                                    
      await message.answer_photo(random_line)
       
      lines.removeat(random_line)
```

'''

Comment: Попробуйте этот способ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/940951/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-txt-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0